# How to extract icon associated with file extension on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, icons

I want to extract the icon associated to certain file extensions to display them in a WPF Desktop application.
I already saw the numerous answers posted on SO on this topic (SHGetFileInfo, Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon, etc.).

Those solutions work fine on Windows 7, but on Windows 8, those methods display the "unknown type" icon for file types associated to Metro apps (for example, PDF files).
Is there a way to display the correct icon in this case ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Nope, so I decided to use my own icon set...